# is there any method to remove this lines in bar chart in flutter

Tags: flutter, bar-chart

I want to remove this line from the bar chart.
Iam using 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart'as charts.
This is part of my code:

```
Expanded(
               child: new charts.BarChart(
                seriesList,
                animate: animate,
                vertical: true,
                domainAxis: new charts.OrdinalAxisSpec(
                  renderSpec: charts.SmallTickRendererSpec(
                    labelRotation: 45,
                    

                  ),
                ),
                primaryMeasureAxis:charts.AxisSpec(
                  showAxisLine: true,
                ),


                // Configure a stroke width to enable borders on the bars.
                defaultRenderer: new charts.BarRendererConfig(
                    groupingType: charts.BarGroupingType.grouped, strokeWidthPx: 2.0),
                behaviors: [
                  charts.SeriesLegend(
                    position: charts.BehaviorPosition.top,
                    horizontalFirst: true,
                    cellPadding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0,right: 15.0, ),
                  )
                ],
          ),

             ),
```

[image]

Comment: Please add more details to your question. For example, what package are you using? Do you have example code? It's really hard to answer this question without additional details.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right then this is your solution.

```
// hide x axis
      domainAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(
          showAxisLine: false, renderSpec: charts.NoneRenderSpec()),       
// hide y axis
      primaryMeasureAxis:
          charts.NumericAxisSpec(renderSpec: charts.NoneRenderSpec()),
```

Comment: i wanna to hide lines which i refers to in picture not X-Axis or Y-Axis

Comment: Here read this, https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/axes/hidden_ticks_and_labels_axis.html